# Trouble visualizing a graph of the sum of infinite Dirac functions

Tags: convolution, dirac-delta

I'm currently trying to solve a problem on my "Signals and Systems" class and I'm stumped.The question has 2 parts:

**1-)** The function T.I can be defined as:
$$
T\cdot I(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-na)
$$

Where $ \delta $ is the delta Dirac function. Make a sketch of the function.

**2-)** What happens if I make the convolution of any function $f(x)$ with the function T.I? Sketch the result of the convolution.

I can't visualize how the graph of the T.I function will look like. The best I can think is that it'll be an infinite number of delta-dirac functions all throughout -infinity to + infinity. However, I don't know how I would be able to sketch that and how a convolution involving the T.I function would ever look like in a graph.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: $$[\delta (t-n a) * f(t)](x)=f(x-n a)$$ so for $$g(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-na)$$ one has $$[g(t) * f(t)](x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} f(x-n a).$$